# How can Machine Learning approaches be applied to Natural Language Processing?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to do a paper about the Machine learning been applied in NLP. Can you guys please suggest me applications that have already used the Machine learning with the NLP?

Comment: This question is too broad IMHO. As you don't seem to know where to start, I am assuming your "paper" is simply about the state of the art (not about actual research on the topic). If this is homework for your University (I see you are an student), then it is probably for you to search and read different papers and come up, yourself, with an idea of the current state of the art. ;-)

Comment: I am trying to get ideas about how to start my project, anyway thank you for your comment @Peque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is broad since machine learning is becoming more and more mainstream.
Regarding text, images and video, a good list of APIs would be:

AT&T Speech, IBM Watson, Google Prediction, Wit.ai, AlchemyAPI, Diffbot and I guess Project Oxford as well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something generic you can use this tutorial: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/papers/tutorial_colt.pdf

It is probably not the more recent information but you could find it useful if you start to learn ML methods for NLP.

As it is mentionned in this tutorial, ML methods are generally linked to the NLP task (Information Extraction, Machine Translation, etc.).

[IBM Watson project](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/what-is-watson.html) is an example of platform that uses NLP and ML.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me a lot